# Flutter Textfield pick from list of options

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a message component in my Flutter app. When a user goes to send a new message, I want the user to only be able choose the recipient from a list of options (i.e. they can only send to a valid username).

The view looks like this

```
                   TextField(
                      cursorColor: etenRed,
                      controller: recipient,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'To: Username',
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: etenRed,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (text) {
                        model.onSearchChanged(text);
                      },
                    ),
                    model.isSearchingForUsers
                        ? SizedBox(
                            height: 150,
                            child: ListView.separated(
                                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Divider(
                                    thickness: 0.5,
                                    color: Colors.black54,
                                  );
                                },
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: model.snapshots.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return ListTile(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      recipient.text = model
                                          .snapshots[index].data['username'];
                                      model.resetList();
                                    },
                                    title: Text(model
                                        .snapshots[index].data['username']),
                                  );
                                }),
                          )
                        : Container(),
```

How do I ensure that the user can't enter a username that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(usernames.contains(model.search)) {
  sendMessage();
}
```

`usernames` is the list of usernames and model.search is the username that the user has typed